# apex class error - Non-selective query against large object type (more than 200000 rows)

Tags: apex, trigger

for aggregating the I results, I used below for loop but I am getting the below error message.

"Non-selective query against large object type (more than 200000 rows). Consider an indexed filter or contact salesforce.com about custom indexing."

can anyone helps me out in this issue here.

```
for (Project__c objProject: [SELECT Name, 
                                (SELECT Name, Billable_Cost__c, Billable_Dollars__c, Non_Billable_Costs__c, Non_Billable_Dollars__c  from Time__r) 
                                 FROM Project__c
                                 WHERE Id in:set_Time ]){
                                     for(Time__c objTime01: objProject.Time__r){
                                         BillableDollars+= objTime01.Billable_Dollars__c;
                                         BillableCost+= objTime01.Billable_Cost__c;
                                         NonBillableDollars+= objTime01.Non_Billable_Dollars__c;
                                         NonBillableCost+= objTime01.Non_Billable_Costs__c;
                                     }  
                                     objProject.BillableCosts__c = BillableCost;
                                     objProject.BillableDollars__c = BillableDollars;
                                     objProject.Non_Billable_Costs__c = NonBillableCost;
                                     objProject.Non_Billable_Dollars__c = NonBillableDollars;
                                     objProject.Total_Costs__c = BillableCost + NonBillableCost;
                                     objProject.Total_Dollars__c = BillableDollars + NonBillableDollars;
                                     list_Project.add(objProject);

                                 }
    update list_Project;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your object has a bunch of records, you should use a field that has an index. You could ask to Salesforce to create an index or use a External ID field in your query.

> 1. You may find that the query in question needs to be more selective in the WHERE clause. According to the Salesforce standards & best
>      practices - the where clause needs to subset 10% or less of the data.
> 2. A custom index on the field.
> 3. A possible quick fix may be to make the field in question an external ID. Since external IDs are indexed automatically, this will
>      create the index and may solve the problem.
>
> In Classic, go to Setup | Create | Objects then click the Object name.
>   In LEX, go to Setup | Object Manager  then Object name. Then, edit
>   field name and check the box External ID.
>
> NOTE: If this does help your query performance, we recommend that you
>   still log a case with support to implement a custom index in it's
>   place. This is not a long term solution for performance improvements
>   and has other designed use cases.

here is the help link -> https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000323572&type=1&mode=1